# Setting initial state in Qiskit unitary simulator

Tags: programming, qiskit, quantum-state

I'm getting started in IBM quantum lab for quantum computing. My task is to put quantum state $|0\rangle$ on the 1st qubit and state $|1\rangle$ on second one. I tried using this method to initialize it as:

```
qc.initialize(0,0)
qc.initialize(1,1)
```

but when I run in the unitary simulator, I get the following error:

```
Simulation failed and returned the following error message:
ERROR: Failed to load qobj: Invalid qobj "initialize" instruction ("params" is incorrect length).
```

I also tried using reset method but it displayed error as well

```
qc.reset(0)
qc.reset(1)
qc.x(1)
```

If anyone knows how to set state to a specific qubit in Qiskit it would be great, thanks in advance

The full code:

```
#Creating a quantum circuit with two qubits
qc=QuantumCircuit(2)

#Set the state of the first qubit to|0⟩ and set the state of the second qubit to|1⟩.
qc.initialize(0,0)
qc.initialize(0,0)
#or
#qc.reset(0)
#qc.reset(1)
#qc.x(1)

#Applying Hadamard to both qubits
qc.h(0)
qc.h(1)


#Applying CNOT operator, where the controller qubit is the first qubit and the target qubit is the second qubit
qc.cx(0,1)

#Applying Hadamard to both qubits
qc.h(0)
qc.h(1)

display(qc.draw()) 
usim = Aer.get_backend('unitary_simulator')
qobj = assemble(qc)
unitary = usim.run(qobj).result().get_unitary()
array_to_latex(unitary, pretext="\\text{Circuit = }\n")
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see the full code leading to the error.

Comment: ok I'll post it rn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your circuit looks like this:

```
from qiskit import *
qc = QuantumCircuit(2)
qc.initialize(0,0)
qc.initialize(1,1)

qc.h(0)
qc.h(1)
qc.cx(0,1)
qc.h(0)
qc.h(1)

qc.draw('mpl')
```

[image]

And you want to run it in the Aer unitary simulator. However, the simulator does not support the instruction `initialize`. So you need to *transpile* your circuit to the instruction set of the selected backend.  You can do that with `transpile`:

```
usim = Aer.get_backend('unitary_simulator')
transpiled = transpile(qc, backend=usim)
transpiled.draw('mpl')
```

[image]

Once transpiled, you can run it in the backend:

```
qobj = assemble(transpiled)
unitary = usim.run(qobj).result().get_unitary()
```

Here is the resulting unitary:

```
from qiskit.visualization import array_to_latex
array_to_latex(unitary, prefix="\\text{Circuit = }\n")
```

[image]

Comment: pretty much, but worst part is how do I do this then: We start in quantum state|01⟩. What is the outcome? Because when initializing I can literally put (2,0) and I will get state 2 which is not possible I think

Comment: I extended the answer based on your comment. Is it answering your question now?

Comment: partially because when I run my code I want to see the measurements but using reset/decompose and initialize method it doesn't allow me, I added my whole code so you can see what I mean

Comment: new attempt. TL;DR, your backend does not support `initialize` and you have to transpile your circuit first.

Comment: Thank you it works :)

Comment: @Don I don't think they will allow you to initialize the state (2,0) like you commented. It will probably throw you an error about the vector not being a unit vector. Similar to the way qiskit will throw you an error if you try to create a gate from a matrix and your matrix is not unitary...

Comment: @luciano I like this `array_to_latex` feature that you guys have included in your visualization package. Very nice.